# Max Vlookup Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the maximum date in a column. For example:

```
Column A
2011
2010
2010
2009
2013
```

I would like the function to find 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are simply trying to find a max value, then Vlookup is overkill.  `=Max(A:A)` will find the maximum value in column A.

If you're trying to do it in VBA, then the function would be `Application.Max(Range("A:A"))`.

Comment: That works fine. However when I try it with a full date such as 15/03/2013, it does not get the maximum, its comes up with 41343

Comment: Excel stores dates as the integer number of days since 1/1/1900.  If you reformat that cell as a date, it will show properly.

Comment: The cell is formatted as a date, I can't seem to see why it's not working